# Django передача данных sqllite->>models->>html

Tags: django, sqlite, pythonanywhere

Есть отдельный скрипт который работает с некоторыми сайтами и записывает выбранные данные в базу данных. Вот его часть связанная с базой данных.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("bgg1.db")
conn.text_factory = str

cursor = conn.cursor()
# delete 
cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE yres;""")
sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE yres ( 
name   VARCHAR(100), 
track  VARCHAR(100), 
number VARCHAR(100),
point  VARCHAR(100));"""
cursor.execute(sql_command)

cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO yres (name, track, number, point) VALUES (?, ?, 
 ?, ?)", 
 (str(td_text[1]),str(td_text[5]),str(td_text[6]),str(df['attribute.name'] 
 [0])))
    conn.commit()
```

Дальше у меня есть джанго проект с подключенным шаблоном..и всем остальным.. и я хочу вывести данные в html файл..не знаю как это сделать через модели или как. И как при запуске проекта запускать мой скрипт? 
Выполнил автоматическую генерацию моделей

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb    
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Создало какую-то модель..а дальше я не знаю что делать

```
from django.db import models


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


class YresAuthor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_author'


class YresBook(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(YresAuthor, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField()
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_book'


class YresBookGenre(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    book = models.ForeignKey(YresBook, models.DO_NOTHING)
    genre = models.ForeignKey('YresGenre', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_book_genre'
        unique_together = (('book', 'genre'),)


class YresBookinstance(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    book = models.ForeignKey(YresBook, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_bookinstance'


class YresGenre(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_genre'`введите сюда код`
```

Comment: Очевидно, учить Django.

Comment: очень "полезный" совет, спасибо.....

Answer (score 0):

все я разобрался!!) Сначала необходимо создать модель, затем провести её миграцию в бд, а затем уже через скрипт записывать данные в эту бд . Ну а после подключить модели в файле представлений, а затем уже и в самом html. Если кому понадобиться вот ссылка не ресурс который мне помог разобраться.

https://metanit.com/python/django/5.4.php